# Access command line arguments in Julia

Tags: julia

When I type in

```
$ julia myprog.jl foo bar baz
```

Where in my code can I go to access the strings `"foo", "bar", "baz"` ?

I'm looking for the Python equivalent of `sys.argv`

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Ah, more web-searching led to the right answer.  The keyword `ARGS::Array{ASCIIString}` holds command line arguments

Here is a simple example

```
# cli.jl

print(map(x->string(x, x), ARGS))  # Concatenate each arg onto itself and print
```

Lets test it at the command line:

```
$ julia cli.jl a b c
aa
bb
cc
```

Answer (score 34):

A simpler example:

> #printargs.jl
>
> println(ARGS[2]);

Run it as

> julia printargs.jl a b c d
>
> b

Note that the array index starts from 1 and **NOT** 0. Thus ARGS[2] prints *b* and not *c* as in case of many other programming languages.

Answer (score 7):

`julia> Pkg.add("ArgParse")`
Docs at https://argparsejl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/argparse.html

Answer (score 2):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getcommandlinea

In the case that you really need the exact args that came to julia including the `-e`, there is a workaround for Windows.  Looking at `/proc/PID/cmdline` you can extract it linux. Mac doesn't have the same `/proc` option, so asking `ps` works nicely.

```
if Sys.iswindows()
    mycmd = unsafe_string(ccall(:GetCommandLineA, Cstring, ()))
elseif Sys.isapple()
    mycmd = strip(read(`/bin/ps -p $(getpid()) -o command=`, String))
elseif Sys.isunix()
    mycmd = replace(read(joinpath("/", "proc", string(getpid()), "cmdline"), String), "\x00"=>" ")
else
    mycmd = string(Base.julia_cmd()) * join(map(x->" " * x, ARGS))
end
```

But typical use cases you only need to look at `ARGS`.

Comment: Just found this: `Base.JLOptions()`.  It shows a lot of detail of how Julia was launched.

Answer (score 1):

The command-line arguments are in the global constant `ARGS` of type `Vector{String}`. Note that `ARGS`'s first element does **not** correspond to the name of the script. That is in the global `PROGRAM_FILE::String`.

As an example, to display each command-line argument in a separate line, you can iterate the `ARGS` vector and print each element:

```
for arg in ARGS
    println(arg)
end
```

or more concise by using `foreach()`<sup>**X**</sup> instead of `for`:

```
foreach(println, ARGS)
```

You can also use `map()` to produce other `Vector`s from `ARGS`:

```
capitalized_args = map(uppercasefirst, ARGS)
println(capitalized_args)

arg_lengths = map(length, ARGS)
println(arg_lengths)
```

Running this file, `myprog.jl`, with the command-line arguments `foo`, `bar` and `buzz`:

```
$ julia myprog.jl foo bar baz
["Foo", "Bar", "Buzz"]
[3, 3, 4]
```

---

<sup>**X**</sup><sub>Using `map()` instead of `foreach()` would have produced a (useless) `Vector{Nothing}` since `println()` returns the value `nothing`. In this scenario, we are only interested in the side effects of printing the elements when iterating over `ARGS`, so we use `foreach()` as it discards the value returned by the passed function. In other words, it is `foreach(println, ARGS) :: Nothing` but `map(println, ARGS) :: Vector{Nothing}`.</sub>