# How to run Julia 0.4 Code with an ASCIIString substitute?

Tags: arrays, string, julia, legacy-code

I'm testing out the Remez library in Julia and have hit a couple of snags. I would like to build the original [ARM reference code](https://github.com/ARM-software/optimized-routines/blob/da55ef9510a53822b5706c61ad97795828999c80/auxiliary/remez.jl) written in Julia 0.4 whilst making as few changes as possible to it. But the user interface has totally defeated me since it uses ASCIIString in a way that I cannot seem to replicate or resolve by any sensible method.

I have looked at the threads on here and most (pre 2015) talk about ASCIIString as still existing. Then it went into LegacyStrings and now it is nowhere. I haven't found description of a suitable workaround and my knowledge of Julia is still very poor so I need some help please. The closest I could find here was this thread which is old enough that [ARGS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21056991/access-command-line-arguments-in-julia) was of type ASCIIStrings. I found a suggestion elsewhere to try LegacyStrings but that didn't work either (same error message) :(

All I really want is some way to declare an array of empty strings so that the rest of the original ARM code can see its parameters from the command line how it expects. Annoyingly the Julia editor I'm using still thinks ASCIIString is a valid keyword :(

I tried declaring it String, AbstractString, Array, AbstractArray and various others but no joy. The compiler's helpful suggestion is clearly nonsensical. I am not seeing the wood for the trees here. I am a complete novice at Julia (about 2 weeks experience) so it may well be blindingly obvious what I **should** be doing here but I just can't see it!

```
argwords = Array(ASCIIString, 0)  ## this line fails to compile
for arg = ARGS
  if doing_opts && beginswith(arg, "-")
    if arg == "--"
        doing_opts = false
[snip]
        else
           error("unrecognised option: ", arg)
        end
   else
        push!(argwords, arg)   ## saves them for later access by main code
   end
end
# compiler output Julia v1.9.3
# ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching Array(::Type{ASCIIString}, ::Int64)
# Closest candidates are:
# Array(::LinearAlgebra.UniformScaling, ::Integer, ::Integer)
```

It was ASCIIString originally. Then I tried LegacyStrings but that no longer offers a compatible way of using this type of declaration. Please can I have suggestions for a minimal changes work around to get this code to compile in v1.9.3 without errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the Array creation syntax that's changed here - looking up `?Array` in the REPL, you can see:

> `Array{T}(undef, dims)`
> `Array{T,N}(undef, dims)`
>
> Construct an uninitialized `N`-dimensional `Array` containing elements of
> type `T`. [...] `dims` may be a tuple or a series of integer arguments
> corresponding to the lengths in each dimension.

In your case, we want the type T to be `String`, and just one dimension of length (initially) 0, so we can write it as `Array{String}(undef, 0)`.

```
julia> Array{String}(undef, 0)
String[]
```

That output shows you an easier way to write it though: just `argwords = String[]` creates the empty `Array` of `String`s you want.

Comment: Thank you. That was the correct answer that I couldn't see for looking. I'm very much a beginner in this language and running package Remez is something of a baptism of fire. I don't seem to ask the help system the right questions to find useful answers :( Marked as correct. Thanks again - now I can make progress with the numerics.

Comment: Porting from the ancient 0.4 to current versions as a beginner does sound like a baptism of fire. Have you come across https://github.com/simonbyrne/Remez.jl already, does it not suit your needs?

Comment: Yes. Thanks.  I'm originally working with that one. It is a quirk in the behaviour of its approximation of rational functions in his version that I want to investigate. I'll post an example of what is going wrong when I am sure that it isn't something silly that I have done. I'm trying out Sollya in parallel (also with a very steep learning curve).

Comment: oh thank you a lot! the inability of remez.jl to generate rational functions well is really annoying. I will give you a lot of Internet points if you figure it out.